# How to extract random element from a portion of a list of tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuple like this one:

```
[(6, 1), (7, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2), (2, 4), (4, 4)]
```

I have ordered it respect to the second element and if you see the first two tuples, (6,1) and (7,1) have both 1, I would like to select a random tuple from the one that have in common the second element and are in the first position, so in this case the one that have 1 in second position.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, you want to select 2 random tuples and compare?

Comment: so for every group that has a common 2nd item you want to get a random first one?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Sujay expected output is (6,1) or (7,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [(6, 1), (7, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2), (2, 4), (4, 4)]
>>> for item in itertools.groupby(l, lambda k: k[1]):
...     print(random.choice(list(item[1])))
...
(6, 1)
(5, 2)
(4, 4)
```

This assumes that the list is sorted (as stated in your question).

If you only want the first element, you can use

```
random.choice(list(next(itertools.groupby(l, lambda k: k[1]))[1]))
```

(which is quite unreadable, actually, so I'll break it down:)

```
random.choice(  # select a random item
 list(          # from the list of results
  next(         # of the first group
   itertools.groupby(l, lambda k: k[1]) # grouped by the second number in the tuple
  )
  [1]           # use the second element of that list (the first is the key)
 )
```

Comment: you might need to sort the list first before the `groupby`

Comment: OP states that the list is ordered according to the second element.

Comment: The expected output should be (6,1) or (7,1), not the other

Comment: You want to stop after the first result? Then just add a `break` after the `print()` function call.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid break usually are not recommended

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question has been answered, here is a solution which does not use itertools:

```
import random

L = [(6, 1), (7, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2), (2, 4), (4, 4)]

G = list(set([ x[1] for x in L ]))

for g in G:
    l = [ x for x in L if x[1] == g ]
    print (l[random.randint(0,len(l)-1)])
```

Output:

```
(7, 1)
(1, 2)
(4, 4)
```